# Get Swatch Internet Time using javascript (and PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, time

I would like to give my users the ability to select the [Swatch Internet Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time) as their time format.

How I'm trying right now:

```
function startTime(){
    var d = new Date(),
        h = d.getHours(),
        m = d.getMinutes(),
        s = d.getSeconds(),
        time = "@"+parseFloat((h*3600+m*60+s*1)*0.01157,10).toString().replace(/(\.\d{1,2})\d*$/, "$1");

    $('#time').html(time);
}
```

According to the description, the swatch time is timezone offset free, so using the user's system time won't work.

The other way I could think of is sending an ajax request to a php file which returns the current swatch time via the built-in `date('B')` function, but then I cannot use 2  decimals, and also It would generate unnecessary traffic.

```
$.ajax({type:'GET',url:'../time.php'}).done(function(data){ var time = data });
```

time.php:

```
<?php echo date("B") ?>
```

There has to be some sort of way to return swatch time in a `@###.##` format, and I'm interested to know.

The `startTime()` function is called using `setInterval(startTime,750)`, so I need a solution that can work in that time period.

Comment: FYI:  yes Swatch as in the watch maker... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time

Comment: @ficuscr It's already linked in the question...

Comment: What about the old dear timestamp? Damn marketing

Comment: This is just a marketing ploy, there are no standardized functions, converters or API's for this, and time is divided into beats, wich uses the decimal system, and not 60 seconds per minute, 60 minutes per hour etc. which makes it a helluva lot of work to make something that really works.

Comment: Works great with lunar calendars?  Now to hook up this abacus via USB :)

Comment: @adeneo All I really need is a constant date that's always the same time zone, and I could start working off of that.

Comment: Well, PHP has the Swatch time built in, I've never tried it, but I see that you're using it with the special "B" parameter. Does'nt that return a date object that you can format just about anyway way you'd like. The [**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for PHP's date() function should have every conciveable way of outputting the date objects values explained in detail!

Comment: @adeno But then there's the unnecessary traffic and delay when calling to a php file.

Comment: how about using this? http://themactep.com/beats/js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript has a function `.getTimezoneOffset()` which returns the offset in minutes from GMT.

Just take the Biel, Switzerland time zone offset (+60 minutes) and subtract the local time zone offset.  The difference should be the offset to give you the Swatch time.  Then do the beat calculation based on that.

You can also just use `.getUTCHours()`, `.getUTCMinutes()`, etc, which is basically GMT.  GMT is one hour before Biel, Switzerland.  So, you can simply add an hour to your calculations from there to get Swatch time.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qF8Bt/

Answer (score 3):

I just had a reason to write a swatch beat function so will post here for posterity:

```js
function getSwatchBeat(date, places = 3) {
  return (((+date + 3.6e6) % 8.64e7) / 8.64e4).toFixed(places);
}

let d = new Date();
console.log(`Current swatch beat for ${d.toLocaleString()} is ${getSwatchBeat(d, 1)}`);
```

It just adds 1 hour to UTC time to adjust to Biel, then divides by 1 thousandth of a day. I don't know how many decimal places the PHP function returns, but that's easily adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to make the solution which @JohnBoker posed in the comments more visible. A [JavaScript Date class extension](https://themactep.com/beats/js) written by Paul Philippov, which I've been using  to this day. The method takes a single parameter which specifies the amount of decimals to return.

```
function startTime(){
    var d = new Date(),
        time = d.toInternetTime(2);

    $('#time').html(time);
}
setInterval(startTime,500);
```

Try it out below:

```js
function startTime() {
    var d = new Date(),
        time = d.toInternetTime(2);
    
    $('#time').html(time);
}
setInterval(startTime, 500)
```

```css
body{margin:0}#time{font-family:monospace;display:block;width: 100%;font-size:2em;height:2em;display:block;text-align:center;position:absolute;top:calc(50% - 1em)}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://themactep.com/js/ppds.date.js"></script>
<span id=time></span>
```

Comment: This works is under BSD license. See original [file](https://themactep.com/js/ppds.date.js).